# Remote debugging python project in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, remote-debugging

I want to debug a python project which is deployed on remote machine. I can access that machine through terminal using `.pem` file. I have cloned the same project from internal gitlab repo and imported the same in eclipse as a `PyDev` project.

In eclipse I see the option to do remote debugging of java application (Run -> Debug Configurations.. -> Remote Java Application). However, I am not able to find the same for Remote Python Application. Please guide me how can I do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only need install Pydev in your eclipse,select your python interpreter and start a pydev server,for stop in any line the aplication put "settrace()" .

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging is a bit cumbersome in pydev.

[Here](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) is the official manual on how to do it (pay special attention to steps 3-4 and note 1).

Since you'll be running debug server at the same machine as your eclipse you'll probably need something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose debug server port (and be able to connect to it from app you want to debug).

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago i used rpdb.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb this worked pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Its not for eclipse, but the best remote debugger (and debugger in general) I can recommend is pudb, which is basically pdb with console UI.

In your case, you need to install `pudb` in running script environment:

```
pip install pudb
```

Then, in the script itself, put:

```
from pudb.remote import set_trace

set_trace(term_size=(80, 24))
```

When your script reach this point, script will print something like this and hang:

```
pudb:6899: Please telnet into 127.0.0.1 6899.
pudb:6899: Waiting for client...
```

What you then need to do is just ssh into remote system and use telnet:

```
ssh remote@machine
telnet 127.0.0.1 6899
```